# Upload Excel file and access it right away as a spreadsheet via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to upload an Excel file via Apps Script (using the GUI file-upload) and have it opened via the script right away to process it.

When uploaded and saved via script (using the file-upload GUI component) the file is not converted. And I do not see any API to have a file converted to a native google docs (either in DocsList or the Docs API 3).

Is there any ways to trigger an export/convert of a document to the native format of Google Docs? I saw some people mentioning using UrlFetch to trigger Docs API events but all said it was not easy. And there it was to upload the file with UrlFetch, not simply trigger a convert to a native format.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I haven't tried this so not sure it works. 
You can login to your Google Drive and under Upload Settings, you can set it to convert automatically each file and not ask for confirmation.

Then try the Apps Script. 
This may or may not work but something worth trying

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no it's not working. The _Settings_ works only when interacting directly with the site, it's not modifying the behaviours of the Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive API can achieve this using the [files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) method. If you add

```
?convert=true
```

Your file will be copied and the copy will be converted to a Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks but I have read that the Google Drive API only supports **OAuth2**, and Google Apps Script currently only supports **OAuth 1.0a** (if I am not mistaken). It would be a nice feature to have directly in the DocsList of Google Apps Script! Would you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Ali Afshar - I'm having some difficulties to build the call to Google Drive API, could you post some example code on how to build it ?  thx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Advanced Drive Service (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

First, you must enable it for you script as it discribed here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
and then you can use it like this:

```
function convertFile(destTitle,sourceFileId) {

  // Set the "convert" property to true.
  var opArgs = {"convert" : "true"};
  // Set the request body to title:<something>
  var resource = {'title': destTitle};
  var response = Drive.Files.copy(resource, sourceFileId, opArgs);

 }
```